# Image behind text with fancy

Tags: graphics, fancyhdr

I want to have an image behind the page number in my latex document, and tried to write it like

```
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{\textcolor{white}{\thepage}}
\chead{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{img.eps}}
```

The problem is: When I first have the line with the page number, and then the image, I only get the image, and if I have the other way round, then I only get the number. How can I have the number in front of the image? Should I use a background image for that?

Comment: What image is it?

Comment: A black tent (i.e. totally black figure, vectorized)

Comment: As in a black triangle?

Comment: @Alenanno: Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,stackengine,xcolor,graphicx}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
\chead{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\textcolor{red}{\thepage}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}}
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\begin{document}
My text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a possibility to shift the image also such that the number is not centered, but slightly shifted in one direction?

Comment: @arc_lupus, one can easily move the page number within the image, by adding the x-shift as the 2nd argument and the y-shift as the 4th argument to `\stackinset`, as in `\stackinset{c}{8pt}{c}{6pt}{inset}{base image}`.

Comment: @arc_lupus The 1st argument to `\stackinset` is the horizontal anchor position, which can be `l`eft, `c`enter, or `r`ight.  The 3rd argument is the vertical anchor, either `t`op, `c`enter, or `b`ottom.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the content in the sequence that you want them layered.

With the above in mind, we can set the image in the `L`eft header, which will be followed by setting of the `C`entred header:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,fancyhdr,xcolor,lipsum}

\fancyhead[C]{\textcolor{white}{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[L]{\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[height=.7\baselineskip]{example-image}}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

The `L`eft header is set in a box of width `\textwidth` which is naturally centred. Adjustment of the positioning of the image may be needed.

If all you want is a white page number on a black background, you can just use

```
\fancyhead[C]{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\colorbox{black}{\textcolor{white}{\thepage}}}}
```

which sets the page number using `\colorbox`:

[image]